# Voting details (reference) missing on help page(s)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting-correction

Reading [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), I'm missing a section about changing votes, especially time limits. This could also be a reference to the page I'm currently searching for an hour (without success). On Meta sites I find a lot of discussion about the actual values (seems more guessing than knowing) or disputes about the usability (and (declined) change requests) for a thing that I cannot find any reference for. Maybe I only searched in a bad way. In this case please help me find the information.

I hereby suggest to make the voting (timing) details more accessible in the help pages.

Comment: [It exists on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/332043). Search process: find the FAQ overview post on MSE, ctrl-f vote.

Comment: Really interesting to read, so thanks. Couldn't this be referred to from the help page(s)? I mean why not a *How does voting work* help page?